# Resistor is always in parallel to a current source and is always in series with a voltage source, why?

Tags: basic

I have a basic question on electronics. Why is it that typically a resistor is always in parallel to a current source and is always in series with a voltage source?

As observed in Norton's and Thevenin's theorems.

Comment: Google Thevenin and Norton equivalent

Comment: Hm. I just put a resistor in series to current source. Will it destroy the world?

Comment: It won't have any effect - a current source already has infinite output resistance, adding a bit won't affect anything except heat up the resistor.

Comment: @KevinWhite It will develop a voltage on the resistor. Which can be useful.

Comment: @winny I was referring to theorems like those in the question.

Comment: Scratching my head trying to figure out if I am missing something in what appears to be a naïve question................

Comment: @Tevor I think it is not naive but poorly formulated question. Obviously the assertion in the title is plainly wrong.

Comment: @Tevor Typically, not always

Comment: Just an observation. Trying to understand.

Comment: There are no theorems in the question. State one with citation and we might be able to address it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Added the theorems I was referring to.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Only if you have access to both sides of the resistor.  If you add a resistor in series with a current source and don't have access to the junction then you couldn't tell it was there.

Comment: @Home The theorems are telling you how to *convert* one type of sources to the other one. They say that an ideal *voltage* source with a resistor in series is *equivalent* (in a sense) to a current source with parallel resistor. That's it. Is your question - why it is true?

Comment: @KevinWhite Besides that, getting some heat is a legitimate use of electrical device.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, exactly that! Why is that true? Ohm's law?

Comment: There is a proof outline and references here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110498/proof-of-thevenin-and-norton-theorem

Comment: Only after you edited the question. It was likely you where not aware. Still, what does google tell you?

Comment: @winny: I was actually referring to Norton's theorem and Thevenin's theorem in first place. Google led me to the wiki page on both theorems.

Comment: No, you said "I noticed this in basic circuit theorems". Good, wikipedia have all the information you need.

Comment: @winny Sigh, I meant the Norton's and Thevenin's theorems in the first place when typing 'basic circuit theorems'!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internal resistance of non ideal current and voltage sources](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/226191/internal-resistance-of-non-ideal-current-and-voltage-sources)

Answer (score 1):

A voltage source has zero internal impedance and, ideally could supply infinite current. To model a more practical realistic voltage source a resistor is added in series. That resistor will limit the short circuit current to (say) 1 amp.

To model this as a current source you can't put a resistor in series because the current source can still generate 1 amp and the open circuit voltage would be infinite. So, if the original voltage source was 10 volts and had a 10 ohm resistor in series, the equivalent current source would be 1 amp in parallel with 10 ohms.

Answer (score 1):

You could always connect a resistor in series with a current source or a resistor in parallel with a voltage source, but here we are just trying to model one of the inherent non-idealistic characteristics of a voltage (or current) source. Namely, the output voltage (or current) changes with the load resistance due to physical limitations in our source. e.g. A 9V battery will decrease in output voltage when trying to provide too many amps.

If you consider a battery (a voltage source):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbXjte.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We put a resistance in series with the source because the output voltage will vary with the load by a simple voltage divider equation. Whereas, if we modeled our source with a resistor in parallel, then the output voltage would always be our ideal voltage (1V below) - not a useful model.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fShXtR.png)</sup>

It's the same for the current source. A series resistor won't lessen the current through the load, but a parallel resistor will leech current by the current divider equation.

Answer (score 0):

Because a parrallel resistor would not change the behaviour of the (ideal) voltage source and otherwise.

The sources set the current/voltage and the resistors would not change that